# How can I add a new node to the begining of my linked list?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a function that adds a node to the start of my linked list. I have created the new node and successfully pointed the new node to the original header in the linked list. I am however unsure how to set my new node as the header for the linked list.

```
void insert_node(BURGER* header)
{
    BURGER* tp1;

    printf("Enter the details of record to be inserted in the format as\n");
    printf("<name>\n<popularity>\n");
    scanf_s("%s", &name, sizeof(name));
    scanf("%d", &popular);

    tp1 = make_node(name, popular);
    tp1->next = header;
    header = tp1;
    //printf("%d", tp1->next->popularity);

    printf("\n\n New record inserted at the start of the List\n");
}
```

Kind Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding to the front of a Linked List in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140784/adding-to-the-front-of-a-linked-list-in-c)

Comment: If that doesn't help suggest doing a search. There are countless posts on Stack Overflow and the internet in general that explain different ways of doing this.

Comment: OT: the correct term here is "head", not "header".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your thought process was right. However, that code doesn't work because you tried to set your new node as the header, and that doesn't work because `BURGER * header` is a *copy* of the pointer to the header. So you could do this instead:

```
void insert_node(BURGER** header)
{
    BURGER* tp1;

    printf("Enter the details of record to be inserted in the format as\n");
    printf("<name>\n<popularity>\n");
    scanf_s("%s", &name, sizeof(name));
    scanf("%d", &popular);

    tp1 = make_node(name, popular);
    tp1->next = *header;
    *header = tp1;
    //printf("%d", tp1->next->popularity);

    printf("\n\n New record inserted at the start of the List\n");
}
```

That way, you are modifying the original pointer and updating the linked list's header.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pass the header, pass the address of the header.

```
// void insert_node(BURGER* header)
void insert_node(BURGER** header)
...
//tp1->next = header;
//header = tp1;
tp1->next = *header;
*header = tp1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this code efficient you have to make certain changes like.
you have to change the return type of function from void to `BURGER *`
and you have to return the new node to the main function and assign
it to the the pointer which points the linked list in the main function.
and your code will be like this.

```
BURGER * insert_node(BURGER* header)
{
    BURGER* tp1;

    printf("Enter the details of record to be inserted in the format as\n");
    printf("<name>\n<popularity>\n");
    scanf_s("%s", &name, sizeof(name));
    scanf("%d", &popular);

    tp1 = make_node(name, popular);
    tp1->next = header;
    //printf("%d", tp1->next->popularity);

    printf("\n\n New record inserted at the start of the List\n");
return(tp1);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

A linked list *is* its first node, so just return `tp1`.